# Flashing multiple images in python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am new to python  and I am working on flashing (displaying) like 516 images in a go. There have been many questions like this before but none helped me.
Here is the code

```
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
for i in range(1,516,1):
    #a=cv2.imread('test01001.tif')
    abb=cv2.imread('This PC\G:\TRAINING\1\test0100%d.tif'%(i))
    cv2.imshow('test0100%d.tif'%(i),abb)

plt.show()
```

The error that is shows is

```
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-709418c86b86> in <module>()
      7     #a=cv2.imread('test01001.tif')
      8     abb=cv2.imread('This PC\G:\TRAINING\1\test0100%d.png'%(i))
----> 9     cv2.imshow('test0100%d.tif'%(i),abb)
     10 
     11 plt.show()

error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:266: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Please help me. I have been trying to rectify this error from many days but nothing helped me. I would appreciate if code is also posted in the answer
Thanks a lot

Debugged code

```
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
> <ipython-input-2-d89d3a2017ad>(11)<module>()
-> cv2.imshow('test0100%d.tif'%(i),abb)
(Pdb) n
error: '..\\..\\..\\..\\opencv\\modules\\highgui\\src\\window.cpp:266: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow\n'
> <ipython-input-2-d89d3a2017ad>(11)<module>()
-> cv2.imshow('test0100%d.tif'%(i),abb)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> <ipython-input-2-d89d3a2017ad>(11)<module>()->None
-> cv2.imshow('test0100%d.tif'%(i),abb)
(Pdb) n
error: '..\\..\\..\\..\\opencv\\modules\\highgui\\src\\window.cpp:266: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow\n'
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3066)run_code()
-> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3069)run_code()
-> sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3070)run_code()
-> except SystemExit as e:
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3075)run_code()
-> except self.custom_exceptions:
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3080)run_code()
-> except:
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3081)run_code()
-> if result is not None:
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3082)run_code()
-> result.error_in_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3083)run_code()
-> self.showtraceback()
```

Comment: HOW have you "been trying to rectify this error for many days"?

Comment: By changing the code and using numpy to display images. Using numpy was another issue. I would prefer using OpenCV over numpy

Comment: So you have not addressed the error (message) about the image size yet? What does the documentation of `imshow` say about the image to be displayed? What is the image size when the error occurs (add some debug output code)?

Comment: Well, that was the only error it was showing

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: You need to go actively looking for what is causing the error! Take a few steps back. Output info to ensure the program does what it is supposed to do..

Comment: I am not familiar with the library but having "This PC" in your file path does not look right. Why do you have that there?

Answer (score 0):

Your file path to `imread` is very likely invalid, so you do not get a proper image in `abb`, which then of course cannot be displayed, so you get the error about the image size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python os module to navigate through directory ,
and you do not need plotting to flash image .

```
import cv2
import os         # import os module

path = r"G:\TRAINING\1"
img_names = os.listdir(path) # return all image names in given path

for name in img_names:
    im = cv2.imread( os.path.join(path,name) )
    cv2.imshow('image' ,im)
    cv2.waitKey(300)  # no of millisecond to wait for next image

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```